# How to deploy app engine codes and storage objects from test to production projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

We separate test and production into different projects. The test project has some codes in app engine and objects in cloud storage. What's the best way to port these from test project to production project?

Do I download the codes and objects from test project to my laptop and them push them up to production projects? Is there a better way to deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to copy all the files from the dev bucket to the deployment bucket you can use the the gsutil tool recursively. The command in order to do so would be:

gsutil -m cp -r gs://dev-bucket gs://deploy-bucket

On the other hand, in order to deploy all the files in your new project, you can use the following command:

gcloud app deploy path/app.yaml --project DEV-PROJECT

If you don't select the project, it will use the one initialized with the gcloud tool.